# Individual data point variance and covariance

Tags: covariance, covariance-matrix, measurement-error, uncertainty

In the paper, ["Data analysis recipes: Fitting a model to data" (Hogg, Bovy, Lang)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.4686v1), individual data point variances are found and used for subsequent statistical analysis. The data and corresponding variances are shown in the image below.
[image]

The paper cites that the full uncertainty covariance matrix for each data point is given by

[image]

How is this convariance matrix for each point found? I cannot get values which are remotely close when doing the typical calculations for covariance

Comment: Presumably, for a given ID (data point), the values listed in the table for that ID are used to populate the covariance  for that ID (data point). For instance for ID 1, upper left element of covariance matrix is 81, upper right element is (-0.84)*9*61. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Not quite. I was originally looking for an explanation of how the values were calculated to begin with, given only the x and y data. But, my best guess is now thay each ID is actually a data set and the reported values are the result of standard statistical analysis to generate a covariance matrix, with each x and y being the averages of that data set

Comment: These data are not "found:" they are *stipulated.*  This table comes with no explanation; it is used only to provide a running illustration for the paper.  The paper gives the covariance matrix only to make it clear what it means by "$\sigma_x,$" "$\sigma_y,$" and "$\rho_{xy}.$"  In effect, the matrix *defines* these quantities.

Answer (score 1):

This Table 1 of the [cited paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.4686v1) presents example data to be used as the reader works through a graded set of exercises. For example, first fit a standard linear regression to the $(x,y)$ values for data points 5 through 20. Then do a standard linear regression to all $(x,y)$ values. Then work through what would be a better approach if you knew the errors in each of the $y$ values (the listed $\sigma_y$), or the error in each of the $x$ values (the listed $\sigma_x$), or if you knew the covariances inherent in each (x,y) pair. These variances/covariances weren't "found" from the data points, just posited by the authors for purposes of illustration.

The comment about the covariance matrix is needed for the last task I mentioned. Table 1 only provides $\sigma_y$, $\sigma_x$ and $\rho_{xy}$ for each data point, while the covariance matrix itself (Equation 26 in the paper) is needed for the proposed approach to cases with "Arbitrary two-dimensional uncertainties." The "full uncertainty covariance matrix" quoted in the question shows how to generate the covariance matrix from the values provided in Table 1 for each $(x,y)$ pair.

Comment: @user21 see if this helps.